# Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "mscomctl"

Tags: vb.net, activex

I have migrated my project from VS 2008 to VS 2013 . but when i build my project i get following warning

Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "mscomctl". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

I have unregistered and than register mscomctl.ocx from command prompt but still error continues.

Comment: Hiya Anu, Did you remember to add a reference to it?
Menubar WEBSITE - ADD REFERENCE

Comment: You'll have to run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library, run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Copy it to your project directory and check it in to source control so you won't lose it again.

Comment: When i run Tlbimp.exe from VS 2013 command prompt, it throws error it throws an error 'Could not load file or assembly 'tlblmpCode, version 1.0.5000.0, culture=neutral,publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified'